# problem with the restored database

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have a database storing user login credentials of my application in a Table. When I backed up and restored my database to another server, the restore is successful but the login is timing out (SQL Server timeout). Even though I increased the timeout, still no luck.Can anyone suggest what can be the reason for that.

Can re-indexing the database help me in the new server?

Comment: I have a table storing User name and hashed password to my application.This table is causing timeout

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

What my colleagues are attempting to say in the comments, is that, they / we are making an assumption that the issue is due to the account / sql login not existing on your new server (the one where you restored your database). The most likely cause of what is going on is that since the login / sql account you use on your original server doesn't exist on the new server it's causing your application / connection to time out.

No biggie... easy fix with two options that come to mind to help resolve the issue.

First option - Manually create a new user with the same name and password then run the following script on the database you restored:

```
sp_change_users_login 'update_one', '[yourDBuser]', '[yourSQLlogin]'
```

This will connect the newly created SQL Server login to the user in the database you are having issues with.

Second option (I prefer this one) - Install / create the `sp_help_revlogin` stored procedure on your original server. [You can find the script here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)

Once it's installed execute the following:

```
sp_help_revlogin '[yourSQLlogin]'
```

This will generate an output like so:

```
-- Login: yoursqllogin
CREATE LOGIN [yoursqllogin] WITH PASSWORD = 0x0200EF889B2ECBF4A17B836A62AE80BC0F718EBF117C73697892B112C3744D04AB18490E8C666C1154F42BC3D0C49346843032AFBFBEBA28CFE018AB1FED25EF2830A5F046E9 HASHED, SID = 0x01, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_POLICY = ON, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
```

Copy and paste the output onto your new server, and you will be rockin' and rollin' in no time.